# How to safely change the type of a pointer

Tags: c++, casting

I have some objects of type A, and I create several A* pointers.
The pointers are grouped in several ways, and after creating the object,
I place several copies of the pointers in different lists (or vectors). 
These pointers are generated in the base constructor.

Now a derived class (in the constructor) wants to replace one of them to B*, where B is subclassed from A. I see two ways to carry out this change. The trivial one is to crate B instances and replace the pointers in all copies as required, i.e. to implement Replace(A*,B*) (of course for subclasses only) that replaces all copies. On one side I think is is rather error-prone (if later I forget some new place). On the other side, *(A*) is connected to another *(A*) objects, i.e. all such connections must be also changed when replacing. (maybe hundreds of changes per replacement).

A cleaner way would be to change the type of the existing *(A*) to *(B*). I guess in general it cannot be done safely through typecasting (typically no new data members, only overloaded, maybe virtual, member functions; but even new data members and function can occur). What are the limitations here?

Any other idea?

Comment: _A cleaner way would be to change the type of the existing (A) to (B)._ It's nearly impossible to change the type of an object in C++. A `reinterprete_cast` might be such way but actually it just pretends that object A would be of type B (but it still isn't). That's why `reinterprete_cast` is just the "fire exit" if there is no better solution and should never be considered as first option. I recommend to make a [mcve] to resemble your issue. To me, it sounds like your design is somehow broken (and you try to fight against wind mills like Don Quixote).

Comment: Maybe you could create a base class which contains the pointer to A, and if that needs to be changed you simply replace this object by an object of type B? But the base class object/pointer does not need to be changed?

Comment: Use interface-only or abstract base classes which represent the API to any sort of A or B object?  Use static polymorphism and duck typing (which entails a fair amount of template glue)?

Comment: @Scheff You know, I am making a base package, and intend to make it as general as pissible. The end users are non-programmers.

Comment: @Rene Probably this will be the solution, combined with a mapping, rather than directly using pointers (to avoid the large number of reconnections)

Comment: @Scheff Not really. But they will see just a graphic surface. :)

Comment: OK. Without knowing details, may be, your issue can be solved by design really. E.g. imagine you present some kind of graph where nodes are stored in instances of `class A` including the relations. Additionally, `class A` provides something to add features e.g. a `std::unique_ptr` (or a vector of such) to hold instances of `class B` (need not to be derived from `A`). This would allow to replace `B` features without changing anything of the `A` graph.

Comment: I must admit that managing arbitrary graphs while keeping consistency after even such (for users) simple modifications like cut/copy/paste/delete can become a nightmare to implement. (At least, this is my personal experience about this...) ;-)

Comment: I can admit that actually I am making SystemC simulation, i.e. need to change objects potentially connected (though signals and ports). Yes, it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think casting the pointers will ever solve your problem, if the classes have virtual functions. When you call one of these, the object pointed to will 'know' (through its v-table) that it is either A or B, and call the appropriate function. You should probably have a function that really replaces the A with a (new) B - but that should be relatively easy, as you can create a constructor for B that takes an A as an argument!

Comment: the problem is not really replacing, but making the reconnections

Comment: Actually, having thought a bit more about this: Look at it the other way round, so, if you make all your objects initially "B", then it's possible to conditionally call any of these as an "A" object (either through dynamic_cast, or explicitly calling a member function with the A:: prefix).

Comment: @Finally, I provide the constructor with the vector of "special points" B*, and the rest I fill with A*